# Среда разработки на C++

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста хорошую программу для программирования в среде C++, заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Обратите внимание на вопрос: [IDE для C и C++](http://hashcode.ru/questions/3592/)

Comment: можу порекомендувати dev-cpp як безкоштовний, вільно расповсюджуваний IDE.  
також є коштовні программи(MS-Visual Studio наприклад)  
якщо вам потрібно писати програми під linux, то можна взагалі не використовувати IDE, замінюючи його на  
gedit(або інший редактор) + g++(або інший, але я іншого не пам’ятаю)

Comment: Так, маеш рацию

Answer (score 2):

Я лично использую NetBeans для всего практически. Единственное что, для разработки на Python приходится использовать версию 6.9.1, потому что модуля PyDev нет для 7.0.1 А вот для всего остального: Java, C/C++, PHP и даже верстку я делаю в 7.0.1 Раньше пользовался Eclipse, но он мне не понравился, уже и не вспомню чем...

Answer (score 2):

Если под Windows, то для начала можно порекомендовать Dev-C++. Хорошие среда - Eclipse, упоминавшаяся NetBeans. Ну и конечно, Visual C++ (есть бесплатная урезанная версия Express), С++ Builder.

Comment: Я тоже Дев-С++ использую , но часто вижу на неё гон...Вроде пока проблем не было чем она так некоторым не угодила?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, разработка Дев-С++ прекращена? Если кому-то интересно, я пишу в SciTE-ru

Comment: Да я вообще 95% пишу для линукса.